# Wordpress custom css and other plugins not working

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I have a website that recently has stopped displaying custom css (most obvious example is header should be blue and is black) and the homepage slider is not working either. I have updated wordpress and all plugins but still no luck. Is it possible that this has been hacked?

The url of the site is: http://sherlockhomes4u.org/

Here is some code as an example

```
/* Header */

#masthead-wrap {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #155392!important;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#navigation .dropdown-menu a {
    color:#fff;
    font-size:17px;
    letter-spacing:0px;
    text-transform:none;
}

#navigation .dropdown-menu a:hover {
    color:#15ABD6!important;
}

#quickcontactwrap {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #15ABD6!important;
}

#quickcontact {
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 5px 0;
    text-align: right;
    width: 980px;
}
```

Comment: pls add your code

Comment: which code in particular?

Comment: have you tried to clear browser cache?

Comment: For example your custom css

Comment: have cleared cache and tried on another machine, same issue.

Comment: Here is some of the code

/* Header */
#masthead-wrap {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #155392!important;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
#navigation .dropdown-menu a {
  color:#fff;
  font-size:17px;
  letter-spacing:0px;
  text-transform:none;
}
#navigation .dropdown-menu a:hover {
  color:#15ABD6!important;
}

Comment: is dificult without code

Comment: please add your code to the question and not as comment

Comment: ok thats done now

Comment: You shouldn't need your `!important` overrides after you get this working, as the css should be loaded after, and specificity will override them by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jumping to it being hacked is kind of a far stretch; the updates you performed may have broken something down the chain.

If you open the inspector in your browser you'll see you're getting a 500 error from your homepage:

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error): http://sherlockhomes4u.org/?sccss=1&ver=4.7.2`

Whenever there's a 500 error in Wordpress, your [php error log](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php5-apache-fastcgi-cpanel) on your server can be helpful for debugging the issue.

It looks like the Wordpress plugin Simple Custom CSS provides this file. If you run the generated code through [CSSLint](http://csslint.net/), you'll see you're missing an ending brace from your plugin-generated CSS:

[image]

[image]

Opening this file in the editor and placing an end brace at the end fixes everything:
[image]

So make sure that brace ends up in your plugin, if it's there but not rendering, then there's an issue with Simple Custom CSS, [and you should file it](https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/simple-custom-css).